# Android ViewPager FragmentAdapter

Tags: android

In my application i have a FragmentPager. Now each Fragment has a next button with which i navigate to the next fragment. Via the next button i know that the user is navigation away from the view. But how do i know if the user has clicked on the tabs. Will the

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
    }
```

function be called when a user presses a different tab ? Can i save the state and restore it on the

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if ((savedInstanceState != null)
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
            mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
        }
    }
```

will this work ? What other way can i know that the user has clicked on the different tab ?

Kind Regards

Comment: onSaveInstanceState will not be called when the user clicks on the different tab. It will be called when your Activity is in background and the Bundle savedInstanceState will not be null only if the application was killed by the system due to lack of resources and restored. There are alot of questions about onSaveInstanceState and restoring state here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for you actionbar/tabs? I recommend that you do since you'll get a cross-version way of working with the actionbar.

In any case, you should [add a listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setTabListener%28android.app.ActionBar.TabListener%29) to each tab before adding it to the actionbar. With the listener implemented you know when a tab has been [selected, reselected and unselected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html)

I'm not sure about when the onSaveInstanceState is called (try it using the debugger!), but with the listener implemented you'll get a fool-proof way of knowing what goes on with your tabs.

Comment: yupse, i use ABS for everything. Will try this.